# Tera Term new user

Tags: usb, teraterm

[image]

I am a new user of Tera Term. I am trying to connect my PC to a debugger and when I try to assign the port I see the Port field in the above figure as empty. May anybody here be kind enough in giving me a solution to my question?

Many thanks in advance

I need to configure Trace32 Lauterbach debugger and the serial-port terminal Tera Term. But unfortuntely, USB ports seem to be blocked - I was not able to connect the Debugger nor the TeraTerm.

Comment: You need to install whatever drivers your device needs and then make sure a COM port shows up in the "Ports (COM & LPT)" section of your Device Manager. Until then, there is no COM for Tera Term or any other terminal program to connect to.  Consult the manufacturer's documentation.